# Filtrar option mediante un select (php)

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

Tengo un problema que no me deja avanzar, estoy desarrollando un sistema empresarial en el cual necesito que los cargos de dicha empresa se vean filtrados al seleccionar una gerencia en específico, el código que tengo funciona pero mostrando todos los cargos que están en la base de datos, tengo un campo clave que identifica la gerencia y el cargo, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo en el option, tendría que usar Ajax? o asignar la opción seleccionada a una variable PHP? gracias de antemano y espero haber sido claro, OJO: "categories=gerencia" "brand=cargo"

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="categoryName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Gerencia a la que Pertenece: </label>
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select type="text" class="form-control" id="categoryName" placeholder="Product Name" name="categoryName">
            <option value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
            <?php
            $sql    = "SELECT categories_id, categories_name, categories_active, categories_status FROM categories WHERE categories_status = 1 AND categories_active = 1";
            $result = $connect->query($sql);
            $taller = 0;
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row[0] . "'>" . $row[1] . "</option>";
                $taller = $row[0];
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="brandName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Cargo: </label>
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="form-control" id="brandName" name="brandName">
            <option value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
            <?php
            $sql    = "SELECT brand_id, brand_name, brand_active, brand_status FROM brands WHERE brand_status = 1 AND brand_active = 1";
            $result = $connect->query($sql);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row[0] . "'>" . $row[1] . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que necesitas, yo siempre he usado Ajax. Le coloco un evento al primer select al hacer "click" que ejecute un ajax pidiendo los elementos del segundo select (cargos) pasandole el id (id_gerencia).

Y con el resultado cargo dinamicamente el select de cargos.

Si no has trabajado con Ajax, consulta este enlace donde explican como hacerlo: https://codea.app/jquery/select-dependientes-de-tres-niveles-en-ajax

Espero te sea útil, saludos!